# Replace line in config file using bash script

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a line as follows in varnish config file.

```
VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
```

I need to replace the whole line above with

```
VARNISH_STORAGE="malloc,${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
```

I need to write a shell script for this. How can I achieve this using sed or should I use something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE}/malloc/' filename
```